# Get Token for CNAME verification on Google with PHP

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I'm having issues to get the CNAME token to start domain verification through Google API with PHP. Basically API returns that I am unauthenticated.

My code look like this:

```
$client = new Google_Client([
    'projectId' => PROJECT_ID,
    'keyFilePath' => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . KEY_FILE_PATH,
]);

$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/siteverification');
$service = new Google_Service_SiteVerification($client);


$body = new Google_Service_SiteVerification_SiteVerificationWebResourceGettokenRequest([
    'verificationMethod' => 'DNS_CNAME',
    'site' => [
        'type' => 'INET_DOMAIN',
        'identifier' => $CUSTOMER_DOMAIN
    ]
]);


try {
    $response = $service->webResource->getToken($body);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

I got

```
    object(Google\Service\Exception)#56 (8) {
  ["errors":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(5) {
      ["message"]=>
      string(15) "Login Required."
      ["domain"]=>
      string(6) "global"
      ["reason"]=>
      string(8) "required"
      ["location"]=>
      string(13) "Authorization"
      ["locationType"]=>
      string(6) "header"
    }
  }
  ["message":protected]=>
  string(844) "{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Login Required.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "method": "security.irdb.api.VerificationService.GetToken",
          "service": "siteverification.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Using PHP > 8, the file PATH has the correct permissions, if someone has some tips I can create a new service account or new credentials to test if it works.

Thank you

EDIT:
Exporte OAuth2 Secret from Google Cloud and tried to use it with

`$client->setAuthConfig('client-secret-site-verification.json');`

Still not working

Comment: Your code is setting up authorization with a token created from a service account. All requests to the Google Site Verification API must be authorized by an authenticated user.

Comment: There is some guide to follow? I've tried to use an Auth0 authorization file instead of the service account, got some issue. When I was using PHP5 on App Engine, was enough use the useApplicationDefaultCredentials()

Comment: Google has an extensive amount of documentation on Authorization including example code. Start with the documentation for the service you are using [link](https://developers.google.com/site-verification/v1/getting_started) Then review OAuth [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2)

Comment: Thank you for the links, I've already checked them but still not clear how to implement it, the logic is already implemented and it works with the default app engine credentials, unfortunately I cannot use app engine default creds anymore. It is still not working :(